# Basic JQuery Slider Not working for Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a Basic JQuery SLider from the following site.
http://www.basic-slider.com/

When I use animtype: 'fade' it works perfectly, but when I use animtype: 'slide' images does not appear.
My code is below.

```
$('#banner-slide').bjqs({

            height      : 500,
            width       : 800,
            animspeed : 1000,
            responsive    : true,
            randomstart   : true,
            showmarkers : false,
            hoverpause : false,
            animduration : 350,
            prevtext  : '<img src="../Images/arrow-prev.png">',
            nexttext : '<img src="../Images/arrow-next.png">',
            animtype :  'fade',
            responsive  : true
            });
```

Comment: can you setup code on jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

the prevtext and nexttext are not supposed to be the image src

add the images in the `<li></li>`

```
<div id="my-slideshow">
<ul class="bjqs">
    <li><!-- Any content you like --></li>
    <li><!-- Can go inside these slides--></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for posting the link. now i am using the jquery slider.